# In smart_ptr constructor, why pass by value and not pass by const ref?

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I've been reading the section on smart pointers in Scott Meyer's "Effective C++" and "More Effective C++." In it, there is an implementation of `auto_ptr` for which the constructor is written as follows:

```
template<class T>
class auto_ptr{
private:
    T* pointee;
public:
    auto_ptr<T>(T* p) : pointee(p) {}
// ... rest of class
```

My question is: why is the pointer in the constructor not passed by const reference? `p` is not changed in the constructor, so `const` seems fine, and passing by reference we avoid any copying. No explanation for this is given.

I also know that `auto_ptr` has been deprecated, but a) the question still stands, and b) I think one sees the same thing with eg `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: A pointer is a primitive, so what's the benefit of a `T * const&`?

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what is meant by primitive. I presume it means basic of some kind (I looked it up and it seems to mean types that are not built out of other types, does that work for a pointer?) In any case, is the point your making that e.g. to copy a pointer is almost trivial in terms of overhead? But doesn't that still leave the issue of const? Because this still informs whoever is seeing the code that p will not be altered?

Comment: _" why is the pointer not passed by const reference? ... passing by reference we avoid copying"_  You avoid copying a pointer by instead creating and passing whatever passes for a reference.  You should ask yourself - what is the cost of copying a pointer and what is the cost of passing a reference?

Comment: Taking `p` by value also tells whoever is seeing the code that `p` will not be altered.

Comment: Why should the caller care if a function mutates its own copy of an address?

Comment: Yes i see now. Basically, theres little difference in doing the copying then passing the reference, and once one is passing by value, const isn't all that necessary. Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any case where passing a primitive by reference will be faster than passing the primitive by value.  Everything else being equal (such as inlining for both situations, or any other optimization).  I'd hope a smart compiler would convert the pass-by-const-reference of a primitive would just do the pass-by-value, using the *as if* rule.

Comment: Given that references don't exist (they are not C++ Objects); in practice they are often implemented as pointers (if not optimised away).  So in most cases passing by reference is passing by pointer to the referenced object.  In the case of passing a pointer by const reference you end up passing a pointer to a pointer.  This is obviously less efficient than just passing the pointer (by value) in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Important notice: `std::auto_ptr` has been deprecated in C++11 and has been removed from the language in C++17. It should not be used in new code.

> why is the pointer in the constructor not passed by const reference?

Because pointers to objects are small objects and the cost of copying the reference is equally costly, and the added indirection is potentially even more costly compared to copying the pointer.